# Regex that matches a string that contains two character groups a certain number of times

Tags: mysql, regex

I need a regular expression to match a string containing:

- minimum 3 times "**ab**"
- minimum 2 times "**cd**"

Example of matching string:

xyz**ab**1**cd**-f**ab**0**ab**_**cd**

I would like to use the regexp in a MySQL query like this:

SELECT `name` FROM `table` WHERE `name` REGEXP '...'

Thank you

Comment: Did you try something? May we see your code?

Comment: So, you are working on a regex for MySQL? Please add the tag and your attempts.

Comment: With MySQL REGEXP that does not support lookarounds you would need `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE col REGEXP '(.*ab){3}' AND col REGEXP '(.*cd){2}'`

Comment: Thank you, Wiktor Stribiżew.  That's an answer.  I wonder only if there is a way to use only a single regexp without 'AND'

Answer (score 0):

This counts the number of (non-overlapping) occurrences of 'ab':

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(str) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(str, 'ab', 'x')) FROM ...
```

Notes:

- `CHAR_LENGTH` counts characters, `LENGTH` counts bytes; probably this distinction is no relevant.
- The example works for any 2-char search string.  For a 3-char, replace with a 2-char replacement, etc:

  `... REPLACE(str, '1234567', 'abcdef') ...`
- Instead of that, you could do a divide:

  `SELECT ( CHAR_LENGTH(str) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(str, 'ab', '')) ) /
            CHAR_LENGTH('ab') FROM ...`

To look for rows with at least 3 copies:

```
SELECT * FROM t
    WHERE ( ... ) >= 3
```